# Updating the position of a button after clicking? (Tkinter Python GUI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

Launching the game puts the buttons in a random order (caused by a function) but when I continue to press the 'Correct' button, the buttons' positions don't update after the loading screen; even though their text updates. The position of the buttons don't update even after the randomPosition function changes each of the buttons' positions. **Is there any way to update the buttons' positions so that the 'Correct' one isn't in the same place after the loading screen?**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

f1 = ("MS Serif", 29)
lives = 3
multiplier = 0
levelCounter = 1
answer2Counter = 0
answer3Counter = 1
answer4Counter = 2

def randomPosition(): #PLACES THE BUTTONS IN RANDOM VARIETY EACH TIME GAME IS OPEN
  global xpos1, xpos2, ypos3, ypos4, random
  random = randint(1,4)
  print("Random Integer Position: " + str(random))

  #CO-ORDINATES FOR BUTTON PLACEMENT
  if random == 1:
    xpos1 = 50
    xpos2 = 730
    ypos3 = 610
    ypos4 = 720
  elif random == 2:
    xpos1 = 730
    xpos2 = 50
    ypos3 = 610
    ypos4 = 720
  elif random == 3:
    xpos1 = 50
    xpos2 = 730
    ypos3 = 720
    ypos4 = 610
  elif random == 4:
    xpos1 = 730
    xpos2 = 50
    ypos3 = 720
    ypos4 = 610

randomPosition()

BtnWidth = 20 

def wrong(self, controller): 
  global lives 
  lives -= 1 
  print("Lives: " + str(lives))
  if lives == 0:
    app.destroy()

def correct(self, controller):
  global multiplier, levelCounter
  multiplier += 1
  levelCounter += 1

  answer1.set(ftvArray[levelCounter])
  answer2.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer2Counter]) #READS 1ST VALUE OF ARRAY
  answer3.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer3Counter]) #READS 2ND VALUE OF ARRAY
  answer4.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer4Counter]) #READS 3RD VALUE OF ARRAY

ftvArray = ['CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT', 'CORRECT']

wrongFtvArray = [['WRONG', 'WRONG', 'WRONG'], ['WRONG', 'WRONG', 'WRONG'], ['WRONG', 'WRONG', 'WRONG'], ['WRONG', 'WRONG', 'WRONG'], ['WRONG', 'WRONG', 'WRONG']] #'WRONG' IS A PLACEHOLDER VALUE

class Game(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frame = {}

        for F in (FilmTV, LoadingScreen):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frame[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(FilmTV)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frame[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class FilmTV(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        global answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4
        answer1 = StringVar()
        answer1.set(ftvArray[levelCounter])
        answer2 = StringVar()
        answer2.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer2Counter])
        answer3 = StringVar()
        answer3.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer3Counter])
        answer4 = StringVar()
        answer4.set(wrongFtvArray[multiplier][answer4Counter])

        #ANSWERS
        Btn = tk.Button(self, textvariable = answer1, command = lambda:[correct(self, controller), loading(self, controller), randomPosition()], font = f1, width = BtnWidth).place(x = xpos1, y = ypos3)
        Btn2 = tk.Button(self, textvariable = answer2, command =  lambda:[wrong(self, controller)], font = f1, width = BtnWidth).place(x = xpos1, y = ypos4)
        Btn3 = tk.Button(self, textvariable = answer3, command =  lambda:[wrong(self, controller)], font = f1, width = BtnWidth).place(x = xpos2, y = ypos3)
        Btn4 = tk.Button(self, textvariable = answer4, command =  lambda:[wrong(self, controller)], font = f1, width = BtnWidth).place(x = xpos2, y = ypos4)

        def loading(self, controller):
          self.controller.show_frame(LoadingScreen)
          app.after(1500, nextLevel)

        def nextLevel():
          self.controller.show_frame(FilmTV)

class LoadingScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      LoadingLbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'CORRECT ANSWER! LOADING...', font = f1).place(x = 50, y = 50)

app = Game()
app.geometry("1260x830+150+5")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to change the button position after they were placed ? You need to forget the button then replace it.

Comment: @T4rk1n How would I do that? Is that do-able whilst using 'place'?

Comment: My first bit of advice is to not try to cram so much into a lambda. Use real functions, it will make debugging your code much, much easier.

Comment: @T4rk1n: you don't need to forget the button first.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'll take that advice on board. Is it possible to replace a button whilst using 'place' positioning?

Comment: @HJC: of course it's possible. Whenever you all `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on a widget, it owns the widget, nullifying any calls to `pack`, `place`, or `grid` that came before.

Comment: @BryanOakley And how would I do that in Python? I'm looking for an example so I could learn how to do it

Comment: Just call `place`.  You already seem to know how to do that. Try it. Experiment a little.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Updating the position of a button after clicking? (Tkinter Python GUI)"*

Here's a minimal example that does *just* that:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_button_press(widget):
    import random
    widget_size = (widget.winfo_width(), widget.winfo_height())
    window_size = (widget.winfo_toplevel().winfo_width(),
                                    widget.winfo_toplevel().winfo_height())
    random_x = random.randint(0, window_size[0] - widget_size[0])
    random_y = random.randint(0, window_size[1] - widget_size[1])
    widget.place(x=random_x, y=random_y)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Place Randomly!")
    button['command'] = lambda w=button: on_button_press(w)
    button.place(x=0, y=0)
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```