# Randomise order of Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a quiz game where a random word is shown and you have to press the right corresponding box out of 5. (shortened down to 2 for simplicity sake). I've gotten stuck on a problem though. The first time I run the code everything is working great and the right corresponding box is always in a random place, but when I go to generate a new word the randomise doesn't trigger so it's always in the same place. The way I've tried doing it is by randomising the value of the column but it only does it once.

The program running:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpDFa.png

The csv file:

```
'hävdatecknare' : 'historieskrivare' ,
'viadukt' : 'vägbro' ,
'otolog' : 'öronläkare' ,
'bonitet' : 'värde' ,
'daktyloskopi' : 'fingeravtryckslära' ,
'grisaille' : 'målning i gråa valörer' ,
'evakuera' : 'utrymma' ,
'bekväma sig' : 'förmå sig' ,
'magnat' : 'rik och mäktig person' ,
'konstitutiv' : 'grundläggande'
```

Below is my code

```
import random
from random import choice, randrange
from tkinter import *
import csv

box = Tk()
box.geometry("900x250")
box.title("Test")
box.configure(background="#2b2b2b")

def word_1():
    global ord1
    with open('filedirectory') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        ord1 = random.choice(list(reader))
    ord_1['text'] = ord1[1].title()
    return ord1
def word_2():
    global ord2
    with open('filedirectory') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        ord2 = random.choice(list(reader))
    ord_2['text'] = ord2[1]
    return ord2

def correct_word():
    ord_6['text'] = guess[1]

def new_kolumn1():
    global kolumn1
    show_word['column'] = kolumn1.title()

def new_word_box():
    global guess
    with open('filedirectory') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        guess = random.choice(list(reader))
    show_word['text'] = guess[0].title()
    column1()
    word_1()
    word_2()
    correct_word()
    print(guess)
    return guess

show_word = Label(box, text="Your word is: :", font="none 20", bg="#2b2b2b")
show_word.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(box, width=10, height=1, text="New word", command=new_word_box).grid(row=1, column=3)

def column1():
    global kolumn1
    kolumn1 = randrange(1,3)
    print("kolumn1")
    return kolumn1

kolumn1 = column1()

ord_1 = Button(box, width=10, height=1, text="ord1")
ord_1.grid(row=3, column=1)
ord_2 = Button(box, width=10, height=1, text="ord2")
ord_2.grid(row=3, column=2)
ord_6 = Button(box, width=10, height=1, text="ord5")
ord_6.grid(row=3, column=kolumn1)

def tab_window(tab):
    new_word_box()
box.bind('<Tab>', tab_window)

new_word_box()
correct_word()
box.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are the contents of `filedirectory`, the csv you are reading from?

Comment: It's a .csv file with about 1000 words as a dictionary

Comment: Can you send it, or a reduced version of it that is enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Please update your question with about 5 lines from your `filedirectory` file.

Comment: I've now done so. Changed the words though since it was all in another language.

Comment: So what is `test_data` and why did you not just post 5 lines from your `filedirectory` file? I'm sure we could cope with `"all in another language"`.

Comment: It is now updated as I believe per your intructions. Sorry for the mishap.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? I'm getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXbzc.png

Comment: I'm not getting the same problem. I am very new to python and programming in general so I'm not sure of the root of the problem. Although the extended file I have everything saved to the variable `test_data`. The expected behavior is for the `kolumn1` variable to get ranomised every time i press the button "New Word"

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the `kolumn1` variable will get randomised, but that will have no effect on the gui. Did you mean to update the column of the `ord_6` button?

Comment: Yes precisely! I've gotten the text on the buttons to work but I have tried searching up a way to update that variable but haven't found one. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061458/updating-the-position-of-a-button-after-clicking-tkinter-python-gui) help at all?

Comment: I believe I found that post when trying to find a fix but as I previously said, I'm new to python and haven't learned classes yet so I skipped that post when I found it.

Comment: What has classes got to do with it? The line I think you want is like: `widget.place(x=random_x, y=random_y)`

Comment: Yes that seem to have done the trick after a bit of tweaking! Thanks for the help.